# Ordem Crescente em C

Tags: c

Poderiam me ajudar a resolver esse exercício?

Peça ao usuário para digitar dez valores numéricos e ordene por ordem crescente esses valores, guardando-os num vetor. Ordene o valor assim que ele for digitado. Mostre ao final na tela os valores em ordem.

comecei meu código da seguinte maneira:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int numero,lista_numero[10],i;

  for (i = 0;i < 10; i++){
    printf("Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&lista_numero[i]);
    
    if(lista_numero[i] < numero){
      lista_numero[i] = numero;
    }
  }
  
  for (i = 0;i < 10; i++){
    printf("%d", + lista_numero[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Não repita perguntas, siga as orientações feitas na pergunta original e então edite-a para que se adeque ao objetivo do Stack Overflow em Português. Os **comentários** aqui foram bloqueados aqui para que possa prosseguir na pergunta [original](/q/589171/3635).